# Not able to access "Azure File Storage" from .net web application hosted on azure vm using system.io

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Not able to access "Azure File Storage" from .net web application hosted on azure vm using system.io. getting exception username and pwd are required, though the drive is mounted on vm

Comment: Please share your code and tell us where exactly are you getting the error.

Comment: What is the user context your app is running as? You'll need to ensure your app is running with the same user context as the mounted drive.

Comment: How to see user context of the azure file storage.

Answer (score 0):

> .net web application hosted on azure vm

Based on your description, your web application is hosted on azure VM, and you want to read/write Azure File storage. I would recommend you to use Azure Storage SDK to read/write the files saved in Azure file storage directly. [This sample code](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/storage-file-dotnet-getting-started/) contains a lot of functions. Hope it helps.